# Open a subtab in service console on clicking custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, service-console

Currently we have a VF page as the Home page of Service Console and have a custom Button to create a new contact record . I would like to open this new contact page in a subtab when the button is clicked. Any sample code will be of great help as I am using Console for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`openPrimaryTab`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_openprimarytab.htm) method.

> ### Sample Code–Visualforce
>
> ```
> <apex:page standardController="Case">
>
>      <A HREF="#" onClick="testOpenPrimaryTab();return false">
>          Click here to open a new primary tab</A> 
>
>     <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/22.0/integration.js"/>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         function testOpenPrimaryTab() {
>             //Open a new primary tab with the salesforce.com home page in it
>             sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, 'http://www.salesforce.com', false, 
>                 'salesforce', openSuccess, 'salesforceTab');
>         }
>         
>         var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
>             //Report whether opening the new tab was successful
>             if (result.success == true) {
>                 alert('Primary tab successfully opened');
>             } else {
>                 alert('Primary tab cannot be opened');
>             }
>         };
>         
>   </script>
>
> </apex:page>
> ```